# Haskell syb Data.Generics not working as expected

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

On a ghci prompt `everywhere (mkT (\x -> 2 * x)) (8.7, 21, "word")` evaluates to `(8.7, 42, "word")`.

I expected the 8.7 to be doubled as well. Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of `mkT` monomorphizing its argument in this particular case, but it turns out there's no broader way to address the issue. `mkT` isn't doing anything wrong.

It's worth looking first at why `everywhere (* 2)` doesn't type-check.

```
ghci> :t everywhere
everywhere
  :: (forall a. Data a => a -> a) -> forall a. Data a => a -> a
ghci> :t (* 2)
(* 2) :: Num a => a -> a
ghci> :t everywhere (* 2)

<interactive>:1:13: error:
    • Could not deduce (Num a) arising from a use of ‘*’
      from the context: Data a
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   forall a. Data a => a -> a
        at <interactive>:1:12-16
      Possible fix:
        add (Num a) to the context of
          a type expected by the context:
            forall a. Data a => a -> a
    • In the expression: (*)
      In the first argument of ‘everywhere’, namely ‘(* 2)’
      In the expression: everywhere (* 2)
```

`everywhere` has a higher-rank type - the first `forall a.` is inside the parentheses. I kind of dislike documenting the type that way - it uses `a` as a type variable in two completely separate ways. But there are two different scopes, and that matters. What it's saying is that any function passed to it must be polymorphic over all instances of `Data`.

But the type of `(* 2)` doesn't match up there. It won't work with any instance of `Data`. It requires more - it requires that it be provided an instance of `Num`. So the error message dutifully reports that it can't deduce `(Num a)` from the context `Data a`. So this isn't going to work. The pieces don't fit together.

This is where `mkT` comes into play:

```
ghci> :t mkT
mkT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (b -> b) -> a -> a
```

Its type is a bit funny. It looks almost like it does nothing at all, but `Typeable` is a funny class. `mkT` actually compares `a` and `b` for type equality, using those `Typeable` constraints. If they're the same, it applies the function you provided. Otherwise, it just acts as the identity function.

What it does when it's applied to a function is where things are going wrong for you:

```
ghci> :t mkT (* 2)
mkT (* 2) :: Typeable a => a -> a
```

It's still polymorphic in `a`, but the `b` it used to have has vanished. It had to pick a specific type `b` to work against, and it did that by defaulting to `Integer`. (See ghc's extended defaulting rules for details on how that works in ghci.) So...

```
ghci> mkT (* 2) 3.5
3.5
ghci> mkT (* 2) 7
14
ghci> mkT (* 2) (7 :: Int)
7
```

At the type level, `mkT` has to monomorphize its argument. That's the only way it can make use of the `Typeable` constraint when used in a context where a relevant variable no longer appears in its type.

(To tie the loop back to `everywhere`, the reason `mkT (* 2)` works as an argument to `everywhere` is because `Data` is a subclass of `Typeable`. The `Data` constraint implies that the `Typeable` requirement will be satisfied.)

So what can you do about this? Well, it's impossible to write it truly generically because of Haskell's open world assumption. Anywhere in the program, any type might be declared an instance of `Num` with arbitrary implementations of `(*)` and `fromInteger`. In order to work with `everywhere`, there would need to be some mechanism to go from knowing something is an instance of `Data` to looking up its `Num` instance. This just isn't possible at run time. Types have been erased. There may be some residues like `Typeable` dictionaries being carried around, but they don't provide any means to look up other instance dictionaries. And while you might be able to envision a language where that sort of lookup is possible, it actually would be very harmful to allow it in Haskell. It would invalidate the ability to reason about types parametrically, which would be a giant loss.

The best you can do is write transformation functions that work on multiple types:

```
ghci> let f = mkT (* (2 :: Int)) . mkT (* (2 :: Double)) . mkT (* (2 :: Integer))
ghci> f 5
10
ghci> f 2.7
5.4
ghci> f (9 :: Int)
18
ghci> f "hello"
"hello"
```

It's verbose and you can probably write something better by hand if you so desire. But it at least works, at least to some extent. And it doesn't require breaking foundational assumptions in the language design, which is always a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplification of your case that doesn't use any `Data` stuff.

```
module MyModule where

dbl x = 2 * x
myId :: (a->a) -> a -> a
myId f = f
myDbl = myId dbl
```

Don't type this to the ghci prompt, rather, create a .hs file and load it.

Now check what type `myDbl` has.

```
Prelude > :l MyModule
[1 of 1] Compiling MyModule         ( MyModule.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*MyModule > :t MyModule.myDbl
MyModule.myDbl :: Integer -> Integer
```

Surprise! Why is it compiling at all? And why the weird types?

Because of the defaulting rules. (Basically, "if you don't know what to do with `Num a`, just use `Integer`"). Since `myId` cannot deal with `dbl :: Num a => a -> a`, Haskell allows it to take the `Integer` version.

Disable defaulting by adding `default ()` at the top, and this module no longer compiles.

`mkT` is no different from `myId` in this respect.